# Run Xtext product directly

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp, xtext, xtend

I am using on Xtext to create my own language. My product uses Xtend to generate from my language to Java and I can right click on the generated Java file to run it. But I would like to right click on my own language file and run it directly, then IDE will go to generated Java file to run.
To do that, I have created a command and contribute to context menu. 
What should I do next to make IDE goes to Java file and run it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Java-launch/launching-java.html